# Why does this print exception?

Tags: java, string

```
String bob2 = "3"; 
System.out.println((int)bob2);
```

I'm unsure of why this causes an exception. Can anyone explain? Pretty sure because of the int on String type, but want to make sure.

Comment: A `string` simply cannot be cast to an `int`.

Comment: Does this actually compile? Tried it in Java8 and it throws a compilation failure. What is the intent of this question? Was this is for understanding or just code in production that results in something that you are not sure of? Either way not sure you want to parsetInt as suggested below instead of just printing it directly, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Well exception says why there is an exception

Comment: You might also want to look into primitive vs class/object. String is an object, while int is a primitive type.

Comment: There's no exception, just a compile error that explains exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right its because of typecasting. If u need to convert String to int use below code

```
Integer.parseInt("3");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

You can't just **cast** a string to an int.

You should **convert** it using [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Integer.valueOf("3");
```

or

```
Integer.parseInt("3");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java whenever you are trying to change type of an entity to another, both the types should have some relation. Like if you are trying to caste a `sub class` object to `super class`, it will work smoothly. But if you try to compare a `Person object` with a `Lion object`, that comparison is meaning less, the same is the logic in casting. We cannot cast a Person object to Lion object.

In your code `bob` is String type and you are trying to cast it to `int` and in Java both String and Integer is not having any relation. That's why Java is throwing Exception, `Class Cast Exception` I guess, this is raised when different types of objects are compared.

But the `parseInt(String arg)` method in Integer class gives an option to convert numeric String to Integer, given that the argument is a qualified Integer as per Java standards.

Example :-

```
String numericString = "1234";
int numberConverted  = Integer.parseInt(numericString);
System.out.println(numberConverted);
```

You can also try these which will tell you the precautions before using this method

```
int numberConverted  = Integer.parseInt("1234r");
int numberConverted  = Integer.parseInt("1234.56");
int numberConverted  = Integer.parseInt("11111111111111111111111111111");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast String to Integer. Change:

```
System.out.println((int)bob2);
```

to:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(bob2));
```

It will create an `Integer` value from the `String` provided with `bob2` variable. You can also create a reference to `int` variable like this if you want to store primitive `int` instead of `Integer`:

```
int intBob2 = Integer.parseInt(bob2);
```